# Google Sheets Indirect/Dependent Drop-down List

Tags: google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dependent drop-down list.  I have reviewed several pages that describe how to do this using the INDIRECT function.  These solutions don't work for me because my data will have hundreds of customers in the list.

Column B is a drop-down of types of foods available.  Select a type of food in column B.

Then, in column C choose the specific food based upon the type of food selected in column B.

Is there a way to do this that will scale to a list of customers that is hundreds of people long?  I can't have hundreds of INDIRECT functions.

Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l_KZ9PWCXxVFbQB59YkrC5Zz-5up7LgjpLX-4aQKO-c/edit#gid=78496884

Answer (score 0):

without using scripts:

create sheet and use this in A2 then drag down and hide sheet

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Data!A$2:Z, Data!A$1:$1='User Sheet'!B2)))
```

[image]

then use this in data validation

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  How do I unhide DROP?

Comment: @Dustin it auto unhides after you click on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hedVY.png